# fullcalendar: Showing empty days in listWeek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

By default "listWeek" view shows only day that has events. How to show anyway all the week's days?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        eventSources: [
            {
                url:  '/ordini/ajax_calendar/',
                type: 'POST',
            }
        ],
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true,
        defaultView:'listWeek',
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible according to the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/)

> **List View**
>
> What is List View? 
>   A list view is a type of Available View that
>   displays events in a flat list. Only days with events are displayed.